# While Looping an Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to understand a book from Don Gosselin on ASP.NET Programming with Visual C#. To solve it I just simply make it to work by adhering to while loops: one while loop is to assign a number to an array element, the other while loop is to display that array. Total array count displays 1 through 100. This should have worked but didn't. Visual Studio 2013 debugger for some reason assigns count = 100, that's why it's failing.

```
<%
    int count = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[100];

    while (count <= 100)
    {
        numbers[count] = count;
        ++count;
    }
    while (count <= 100)
    {
        Response.Write(numbers[count] + "<br />");
        ++count;
    }

%>
```

Comment: There is also an off-by-one bug here. Arrays are declared with a 1-based number indicating the number of elements, but they are accessed with a 0-based index. You have `count <= 100` in your code, but it should either be `count <= 99` or `count < 100`.

Comment: Another way of saying that is this: With how you've declared your array `int[] numbers = new int[100];`, the `numbers` array has valid elements `numbers[0]` through `numbers[99]`, which is 100 total elements. But attempting to access the 101st element, `numbers[100]`, will throw an exception.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders will keep it in mind.

Comment: @CharlieKilian yes I make that mistakes a lot that an array starts with 0 index as mentioned by the other person here. Darn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the count to 0 before you attempt the next while statement. Currently, the first loop ends when it reaches a count equal to 101. WHen you proceed to the next while, the count is 101 so the loop automatically ends. Just set count = 0; before the second while loop.

Comment: Also, forgot to add that this is also a dangerous way to do it since it's never checking the array bounds before an operation and could lead to an out of bounds array access and throw an exception.

Comment: Hello @MarkFitzpatrick I always make that mistake that an array index starts with 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should set count to 0 after first while loop:

```
int count = 0;
int[] numbers = new int[100];

while (count <= 100)
{
    numbers[count] = count;
    ++count;
}
count = 0;
while (count <= 100)
{
    Response.Write(numbers[count] + "<br />");
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very convoluted and unrealistic way of using while loops and arrays. In order to understand it better, it may be worth thinking about it per step.

```
var i = 0;

while (i < 100)
{
    Response.Write(++i + "<br />");
}
```

The first important distinction is between `i++` and `++i`. The former utilises the value, and then increments by one; the latter, increments the number and then utilises the value.

In C#, you should really be working with Collections, rather than Arrays. Arrays are zero-indexed, and are renowned for causing serious errors, including exposing potential exploits. Being statically allocated, there is no failsafe when attempting to access indicies outside of the bounds of the Array. Collections, on the other hand, are (for the most part) one-indexed, dynamically allocated, and provide fallbacks when accessing indicies. The most commonly used Collection is a List.

```
var i = 1;
var list = new List<int>();

while (i <= 100)
{
    list.Add(i++);
}
```

For the second while loop, it's not really suitable to use a while loop here, for any practical example. The excercise is forcing while loops where they are not needed. In this instance, the aim is to iterate through each element in the array (List) and dump its contents to the screen. Because we want to perform an action for each element, a while loop may cause issues. If the array has less than 100 elements, the program will crash, if the array has more than 100 elements, we'll miss some of them. By using a `foreach` loop, instead of a while, we can eliminate these potential errors.

```
foreach (var num in list)
{
    Response.Write(num + "<br />");
}
```

Now, I realise that the excercise is about while loops, however, it is teaching you to use them in the wrong way. A much better way - and how you'll most often use them - is to perform an action until a particular condition is met, rather than for simple iteration. By this, I mean, a condition is set to false, then inside the while loop, we manipulate a variable, test the condition, and if it's still false, we go round again. The most common example of this is to work out factorials of numbers.

```
var num = 5;
var factorial = 1;

while (counter > 1)
{
    factorial *= num--;
}

Response.Write(String.Format("{0}! = {1}", input, factorial));
```

The other main way in which while loops are used is to force an infinite loop, unless a break condition is met. I'll show a very arbitrary use of this here, but a real world example would be the `loop()` method in Arduino C coding, or a HTTP Listener that constantly repeats the same procedures, until stopped.

```
var stop = 13;
Response.Write("Pick a number between 1 and 100...<br /><br />");
while (true)
{
    var num = new Random().Next(1, 101);
    Response.Write(num + " ..... ");
    if (num == stop) break;
    Response.Write("You got lucky!<br />");
}
Response.Write("Unlucky for you!);
```

The best way to learn these things is to practice them. Pick a task and find out just how many ways there are to complete it. There is one last important distinction to mention though. a `while` loop tests the condition at the beginning of the loop. A `do while` loop, tests the condition at the end.

```
while(false)
{
    // This code will never be run.
}
```

Compared to:

```
do
{
    // This code will be run once only.
}
while(false)
```

As a final thought, here's how I'd write the original code (using a LINQ foreach loop):

```
var numbers = new List<int>();

for (var count = 1; count <= 100; count++)
{
    numbers.Add(count);
}

numbers.ForEach(num => Response.Write(num + "<br />")));
```

Comment: Hello @ApacheTech I know there's a better way but it's just an exercise that I'm trying to solve thinking what the author had in mind not what the best practice or something to that nature.

Comment: I understand that, hence why I was trying to be sensitive in my response. :) I wanted to expand on where and when while loops should and shouldn't be used. Good luck with your studies.