# Comparing an int to an array while converting a for-loop to a while-loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Working on a homework question, I'm given the task to re-write a for-loop to a while-loop with this as the for-loop snippet:

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

What I've come up with so far is what I believe to be close, but I may be completely wrong. I've looked in my book and on the internet trying to figure out what's incorrect about the re-write. The re-write is below:

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

int i;
while (i = numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: the condition is not going to change. both are loops. in both cases the condition is a "while condition"

Comment: you have not used the increment operator anywhere in your while

Comment: @XetriousLee I have given you a break down on some simple little tricks to use when doing conversion of for loops to while loops, if I were you I would google and get a head start on learning how to use a `foreach` loop which does not use the `++` increment but it's `Enumerable` this will be useful to understand and learn as your course progresses

Comment: i don't see how looking into `foreach` right now will help him out with this topic. This topic seems to be explaining a general concept of loops. `foreach` is a little code specific and off topic

Answer (score 2):

you don't seem to be incrementing your i value inside the while loop and the condition has to be changed to something like this i < numbers.Length

Comment: Thank you so much, when the code was changed to your suggestion, the issue was resolved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite like this :

```
int i=0;
while(true)
{
if(i<numbers.Length)
break;

Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
i++;

}
```

or else you can put the if condition in while itself...

Comment: any advantage of breaking an infinite loop instead of using the condition directly?

Comment: Not really, as he is not aware of the while loop and all, after reading he can come to know the advantage of break statement also. that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Don't really want to give a complete answer to the assignment. But this should help:

A for loop consists of three parts:

1. The first part would run **before** the loop begins
2. The second part is a **while condition**. The loop runs while this condition is still true. This is usually the trickiest part.
3. The third part runs each time **after** running the body of the loop

Now a while condition simply has the second part: the while condition. So you will need to re-order the rest of the loop accordingly when changing from a for to a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

int i = 0;
while (i < numbers.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You have to increment the value of i like above and condition should be as `i < numbers.Length` and look at this great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198085/while-looping-an-array)

Comment: some beginners will see that and write it literally and then comment back `it doesn't work` both our answers are correct so it's all good.

Comment: @MethodMan yeah it's true

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
int i = 0;
while (i < numbers.Length)
{
   Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Make sure to initialize declared variable `int i;` or you will get an warning / error

Also the `i++` in this line `(for i=0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)` tells the counter for your variable `i` to increment by `i + 1` the `<` sign tells you that it will iterate at a zero-base starting from 0,1,2,3 which is 4 times .NET arrays are `0 based` so to transpose that into a `While Loop` the key things to look at are the following

> i which is your variable, you should always initialize to a value normally 0
>
> the < sign, tells you that you will use that in your while loop vs a <=`
>
> lastly, the `i++` at the bottom of the while loop says , increment `i` by 1 which is `i++` which translates to `i = i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
int i = 0;
while (i < numbers.Length)
{
   Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
   i++;
}
```

its a very easy way . only problem in your code is while condition and you are not increment a i which is referring an index of an array.